# How to delete common index values with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

I have a pandas df sourced from a csv file. There is a common value within the index column for all entries. How can I remove this common value? The common value is '00:00:00'

```
 Date/Time
 2021-01-04 00:00:00                           Compost Maker
 2021-01-05 00:00:00                    Green Up Feed & Weed
 2021-01-05 00:00:00              Nippon Mouse Trap in a Box
 2021-01-06 00:00:00                  Organic Liquid Seaweed
 2021-01-06 00:00:00                  Organic Rooting Powder                                      
 Name: Product, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is your index column `Date/Time` of type string or is it a datetime object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will set your index as string, removing the " 00:00:00" part:

```
df.index = [str(df.index[i]).replace(" 00:00:00", "") for i in range(len(df))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).normalize()
```

Result:

```
print(df)

                               Product
Date/Time                             
2021-01-04               Compost Maker
2021-01-05        Green Up Feed & Weed
2021-01-05  Nippon Mouse Trap in a Box
2021-01-06      Organic Liquid Seaweed
2021-01-06      Organic Rooting Powder
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df['Date/Time'] = df['Date/Time'].str.extract(r'(\d+-\d+-\d+)')
```

Using regex should work.